# How to stop a running QThread process in PyQt?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, pyqt6

I have a PyQt6 application which aims to detect objects. I inherited QThread to a user-defined class named "**StartProcessWorkerThread**" to create a worker instance once a start button (a QPushButton) gets clicked by the user.

This is the worker class that inherited from the QThread class

```
class StartProcessWorkerThread(QThread):

processing_finished = pyqtSignal(dict)  # Signal for determining if the thread/worker has finished
progress_updated = pyqtSignal(int)  # Signal for determining if the progress bar value was updated

# Initialization
def __init__(self, input_video_filepaths, weapons_to_detect, clothings_to_detect_and_colors, username):
    super().__init__()
    self.input_video_filepaths = input_video_filepaths
    self.weapons_to_detect = weapons_to_detect
    self.clothings_to_detect_and_colors = clothings_to_detect_and_colors
    self.username = username

# Run method that emits the resulting data after running the method run_main_driver_code()
def run(self):
    table_data = self.run_main_driver_code()
    self.processing_finished.emit(table_data)

# This method is ran by run() method which runs the imported main_driver_code() from another .py file
def run_main_driver_code(self):
    user_specific_table_data = cwd.main_driver_code(
        input_video_filepaths = self.input_video_filepaths,
        weapons_to_detect = self.weapons_to_detect,
        clothings_to_detect_and_colors = self.clothings_to_detect_and_colors,
        username=self.username,
        progress_callback=self.progress_updated
    )

    return user_specific_table_data # returns the data returned by the imported main_driver_code() function or method from another .py file
```

From a QMainWindow() instance (i.e., the main window of the application), after clicking the start button, a method gets called which creates the worker or thread instance and uses its methods to start or run the **cwd.main_driver_code()** from earlier. This is how the instance is created and how it gets started and get it running:

```
  self.worker = StartProcessWorkerThread(filtered_video_filepaths, weapons_to_detect, clothings_to_detect_and_colors, self.userloginname.text()) # Create thread worker instance and pass necessary parameters
  # Start running the thread worker instance to detectm generate table data, and update QTableWidget in main section with it
  self.worker.start() 
  # When the PyQt signal (progress_updated) gets updated from detect_weapon.py or detect_clothings.py, update the value of QProgressBar with the emitted value (detect_weapon.py - Line 255; detect_clothings.py - Line 290)
  self.worker.progress_updated.connect(self.updateProgressBar) 
  # When the PyQt signal (processing_finished) is finished, update the table data by executing self.updateTableData
  self.worker.processing_finished.connect(self.updateTableData) 
  # Enable input widgets after the thread worker is finished detecting and providing the table data
  self.worker.finished.connect(self.disableEnableDetectionButtons) 
  # Show Start Button again and hide the Progress Bar
  self.worker.finished.connect(self.hideUnhideStartButtonAndProgressBar)
```

I tried the methods **quit()** and **exit()** but these did not stop or the StartProcessWorkerThread(QThread) instance. I also tried the **terminate()** method which stops the process but the app hangs and crashes after pressing or clicking the start button again.

Does anyone have an idea on how to stop this StartProcessWorkerThread(QThread) instance that is currently running without any problems after doing so? Any answers or suggestions will be highly appreciated. If more information is needed, ask away and I'll do what I can to provide them. Kindly refer to the comments for the details or explanations for each line. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You could construct `run_main_driver_code` so that it regularly checks `isInterruptionRequested()` and returns when that's True. You can then stop the thread by calling `requestInterruption()` on it.

Comment: Hi, mahkitah. Thank you for your response. Do you know how I can regularly check the value of isInterruptionRequested() in my thread/worker instance?

After doing that (assuming that I did it already), how can I actually stop the thread from running if the value of isInterruptionRequested() becomes True?

Comment: The thread will stop running when `run()` returns and that happens when the underlying process in `run_main_driver_code()` returns. So the trick to making the thread stop is making that process stop. How you do that depends on the specifics of the function. Is `cwd.main_driver_code` your own code? If so, you can make the callback function return the value of `isInterruptionRequested()` and have `cwd.main_driver_code` break itself off when it's True.

Comment: Hi, mahkitah. Yes, `cwd.main_driver_code` is my own code. Based on what you said, does that mean I need know the value (True or False) of `isInterruptionRequested()` **during runtime** in `cwd.main_driver_code` which is from another .py file?

Comment: Yes, and that would be pretty easy since you already use a callback function. You define a method in the thread that emits the `progress_updated` signal but also returns the value of `isInterruptionRequested()`. You use that method as the callback. That way you can know the value in  `cwd.main_driver_code`  during runtime.

Comment: Hi, mahkitah. If I did that, can I read the contents of the `pyqtSignal` that will contain the value of the `isInterruptionRequested()` in the cwd .py file so that from there, I can create a return statement that would quickly end the thread?

Comment: The signal has nothing to do with stopping the tread. You use the return value of the callback function to make your process stop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a minimal example of how you can stop a running thread. You don't actually stop 'the thread' but the process that's running in the thread.

Since a callback function was already used, it makes sense to use a callback to stop the process. The callback function serves two purposes: It emits the `progress_update` signal, and returns the value of `isInterruptionRequested()`. That way `long_process` knows whether it should continue by checking the return value of the callback function.

```
import time
from typing import Callable

from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QLabel, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt6.QtCore import QThread, pyqtSignal


class Worker(QThread):
    progress_update = pyqtSignal(int)

    def run(self):
        long_process(self.callback)

    def callback(self, update: int):
        self.progress_update.emit(update)
        return self.isInterruptionRequested()


def long_process(callback: Callable):
    for i in range(1000):
        time.sleep(0.5)
        if callback(i):
            break


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.worker = Worker()
        label = QLabel()
        self.worker.progress_update.connect(lambda i: label.setText(str(i)))
        self.worker.finished.connect(lambda: label.setText('finished'))

        p1 = QPushButton('start')
        p2 = QPushButton('stop')

        p1.clicked.connect(self.worker.start)
        p2.clicked.connect(self.worker.requestInterruption)

        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(label)
        layout.addWidget(p1)
        layout.addWidget(p2)


app = QApplication([])
win = Window()
win.show()
app.exec()
```

Comment: Hi, mahkitah. Your minimal example for stopping a thread in PyQt helped me a lot in understanding your answer and doing what I wanted to implement. The signal really had nothing to do with stopping the thread but instead, the return value of the callback function (which is the value of self.isInterruptionRequested()) that was passed to the function which in my case is the`cwd.main_driver_code()`. I'll be posting snippets of the modified version of the code as answer so that others can refer to it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the minimal example of stopping a QThread from @mahkitah. These are the snippets of the modified version of the code that is now able to cancel the thread (in a way).

The StartProcessWorkerThread(QThread) from the main file (let's say main.py):

```
class StartProcessWorkerThread(QThread):

processing_finished = pyqtSignal(dict)  # Signal for determining if the thread/worker has finished
progress_updated = pyqtSignal(int)  # Signal for determining if the progress bar value was updated

# Initialization
def __init__(self, input_video_filepaths, weapons_to_detect, clothings_to_detect_and_colors, username):
    super().__init__()
    self.input_video_filepaths = input_video_filepaths
    self.weapons_to_detect = weapons_to_detect
    self.clothings_to_detect_and_colors = clothings_to_detect_and_colors
    self.username = username

# Callback method or function that returns the value of the instance's isInterruptionRequested() - used for cancelling QThread instance
def interrupt_thread(self):
    return self.isInterruptionRequested()

# Run method that emits the resulting data after running the method run_main_driver_code()
def run(self):
    table_data = self.run_main_driver_code()
    self.processing_finished.emit(table_data)

# This method is ran by run() method which runs the imported main_driver_code() from another .py file
def run_main_driver_code(self):
    user_specific_table_data = {} # Initially set the variable to be returned after the process to an empty dict (can be anything actually)

    # Instead of returning something, I implemented a try-except statement
    # So that if I raised an exception from cwd.main_driver_code when self.interrupt_thread() == True, I can catch it here with the except keyword
    try:
        user_specific_table_data = cwd.main_driver_code(
            input_video_filepaths=self.input_video_filepaths,
            weapons_to_detect=self.weapons_to_detect,
            clothings_to_detect_and_colors=self.clothings_to_detect_and_colors,
            username=self.username,
            progress_callback=self.progress_updated,
            cancel_callback=self.interrupt_thread # Pass the interrupt_thread method or function
        )
    except Exception as e: 
        print(f"Cancel button clicked. Cancelling operation.")


    return user_specific_table_data
```

The method or function executed when cancel button gets clicked from the main file (let's say main.py):

```
 def cancel_detection_process(self):
    self.worker.requestInterruption()
```

Snippet from the other file that contains long running code (let's say cwd.py):

```
 # Snippet from cwd .py
 # I made the callback function as a value in a dictionary so I called it using the key and added "()" to obtain the self.isInterruptionRequested (boolean)
 if progress_data['cancel_callback']():
     print(f"progress_data['cancel_callback'] = {progress_data['cancel_callback']()}") # Display to know the value of self.isInterruptionRequested (boolean)
     raise Exception # raise Exception to that it falls back instantly to the main .py
```

Basically, what I did is created a callback function in the QThread instance, `self.interrupt_thread()`, that returns the value of the current instance's `self.isInterruptionRequested()` which becomes **True** when the button gets clicked due to `self.worker.requestInterruption()`. After that, I passed the callback function to the long running process (`cwd.py` in my case) where its return value gets constantly checked. I called the callback function (with "()" to get the boolean value) and created a conditional (still in `cwd.py`) so that if it becomes **True**, I'll **raise an exception**. I'll catch it with the `except` keyword (now I'm in `main.py`). Now, the long running process was finished earlier because of the exception raised which stops the thread in a way.

I hope the approach I took with the help of @mahkitah is understandable for those who want to implement this also but is having a hard time.